# Cant Animate Rig Constraint Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I cant change Two Bone IK Constraint weight with animation. When im calling animation using

`animator.Play("Name");` everything in animation changes (transform position, rotation) except rig constraint weight. But if i start it in animation window or use "jump to state" option in animator window everything works

How do i make things work from animation?